# How to run service in background every 1 minute

Tags: android, service

I need the service to be started every 1 minutes that run in background even if my application is not running

Here is part of the code:
`

I use the timer to handle call every 1 minute

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask hourlyTask = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                public void run() {
                    try {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(ServiceMain.this, LocationMonitoringService.class);
                        startService(intent);


                        //   Toast.makeText(testServiceMain.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                }
            });


        }
    };


    timer.schedule(hourlyTask, 3, 1000 * 10);


}
```

`
Thank you

Comment: Instead of starting the service periodically, I think it would be better if you keep the service running and run a timer inside the service, to do your work at the scheduled intervals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android TimerTask Example 
TimerTask Represents the task will run specified time and it will run only once or Repeat.
Create new Class new TimerTask. 
TimerTask Having two methods.

```
    -->
        1 .scheduledExecutionTime() // Repeat Task
        2 .schedule() //Only once
        Timer singleTask=new Timer();
        Timer repeatTask=new Timer();

        int singleTaskInterval=3000; // 3 sec
        int repeatInterval=10000; // 10 sec

        // this task for specified time only once it will run
        singleTask.schedule(new TimerTask(){
@Override
public void run(){
// Here do something
// This task will run 3 sec only once.
        }
        },1000);

        // this task for specified time it will run Repeat
        repeatTask.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
@Override
public void run(){
// Here do something
// This task will run every 10 sec repeat
        }
        },0,repeatInterval);

        When your activity went to destroy or stop.you should cancel this task
        -->-->
@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        if(singleTask!=null){
        singleTask.cancel();
        }
        if(repeatTask!=null){
        repeatTask.cancel();
        }
        }
        Activity Code

/**
 * @author vijayakumar
 */
public class AndroidMADQAActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    Timer singleTask = new Timer();
    Timer repeatTask = new Timer();
    int singleTaskInterval = 3000; // 3 sec
    int repeatInterval = 10000; // 10 sec

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        singleTask.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
// Here do something
// This task will run 3 sec only once.
            }
        }, 1000);
        repeatTask.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
// Here do something
// This task will run every 10 sec repeat
            }
        }, 0, repeatInterval);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (singleTask != null) {
            singleTask.cancel();
        }
        if (repeatTask != null) {
            repeatTask.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Alarm Manager of android which will start your service in what time you have set in Alarm Manager

Look at this developer guide

http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Answer (score 0):

For Timer do like this

```
Timer timer = new Timer() ;
MyTimer myTask = new MyTimer (timer) ;
int firstSart = 1000 ; // it means after 1 second.
int period = 1000*60 ; //after which the task will repeat;(After 60 seconds)
timer.schedule(myTask, firstSart, period) ;//the time specified in millisecond
```

Create separate class for timer & put service there or you can pass through constructor in case of generic code-

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
/* This is scheduler class which have scheduleing operation logic*/
public class MyTimer extends TimerTask {

    Timer timer ;
    int count = 0 ;

    public MyTimer () {

    }

    public MyTimer ( Timer timer ) {
        this.timer = timer ;
    }

    public void toDo() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ServiceMain.this, LocationMonitoringService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void run () {
        toDo () ;

        if (count > 10) {
            // this is the condition when you want to stop the task here i have not incriges the value of count
            //so it will run in infinite loop.
            timer.cancel () ;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use in code

```
    Timer timer ;
    int count = 0 ;

 if (count > 10) {
            // Enter your code 
            //It will run N number of time
            timer.cancel () ;
        }
```